# Access label text in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have created a timer class in swift and when a user clicks a button I segue to another view and pass data between the two views. The time class uses 3 separate labels for hour, minute and second however I would like to pass all 3 in a single variable.

My question is, how do I access the text inside a label. If I use `"\(hourLabel.text)"` (for example) I get a message `"Optional(00)"`.

Comment: Have you tried unwrapping the Optional? `if let myLabel = hourLabel.text {do_something_with_mylabel}`

Comment: Could you post all of the code (the whole View controller) so that we can better help you

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to access another view controller's view objects (a UILabel, for example) don't do that. It violates the principle of encapsulation, and also often doesn't work.

If try to evaluate hourLabel.text where hourLabel is an outlet in your current view controller, the outlet link is probably broken (and nil.)

Post the actual code you are trying to use.

Comment: No I am not trying to access the UILabel as such. I want to pass the value from one view controller to another. The timer for instance updates every second and when a user presses a stop button, I want to pass the value to the next view. I am doing this through prepareForSegue.

Answer (score 0):

code this in viewController1 aka main view controller

```
@IBOutlet weak var sendBtn : UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    sendBtn.addTarget(self,action:#selector(buttonClicked(_ :)), forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
} 


@objc func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton){
    guard let hour = hourLbl.text, let mins = minLbl.text, let sec = secLbl.text else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "ERROR", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        self.present(alert, animated: true){
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                alert.dismiss(animated; true, compleation: nil)
            }
        }
        return 
    }
    
    let timeString = "\(hour):\(mins):\(sec)"
    
    // now its ready to send data to next viewController
    
    let vc = self.UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewController.storyboard.id") as! viewControllerFileName 
    
    // Assigning value 
    vc.storeText = timeString
    
    // moving to next vc
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

}
```

code this in viewController2

```
class viewController2 : UIViewController {

    // create UIlabel for temp var data
    @IBOutlet weak var someTimeLbl: UILabel!
    
    // create a temp var 
    var storeText: String!
    
    override viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        someTimeLbl.text = storeText
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the text inside a label in Swift, you can use optional unwrapping. If you get a message like "Optional(00)," it means the label's text property is optional. You can handle this by using the nil coalescing operator (**`??`**).

Here's an example of one label:

```
let hourText = "\(hourLabel.text ?? "00")"
```

Repeat this pattern for the minute and second labels. Now, you can pass all three values into a single variable when segueing to another view controller.

Here's an example with a segue:

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let hourText = "\(hourLabel.text ?? "00")"
    let minuteText = "\(minuteLabel.text ?? "00")"
    let secondText = "\(secondLabel.text ?? "00")"

    let timeString = "\(hourText):\(minuteText):\(secondText)"

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "YourSegueIdentifier", sender: timeString)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "YourSegueIdentifier" {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? YourDestinationViewController {
            destinationVC.receivedTimeString = sender as? String ?? "00:00:00"
        }
    }
}
```

In the destination view controller (YourDestinationViewController), you can now use `receivedTimeString` to access the combined time values.

Here's an example of how you can handle the received time string in the destination view controller (YourDestinationViewController):

```
import UIKit

class YourDestinationViewController: UIViewController {
    // Assume you have a variable to store the received time string
    var receivedTimeString: String = "00:00:00"

    @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel! // Connect this to a label in your destination view controller

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Now you can use the receivedTimeString in this view controller
        print("Received Time String: \(receivedTimeString)")

        // Assuming you want to display the time in a label, update the label's text
        timeLabel.text = receivedTimeString
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this...

```
if hourLabel.text != "" {
println("\(hourLabel.text!)")
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as text being nil only text being blank like this "".

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try this...

```
if(!hourText.text){
// Do something...
}
```